# Please Explain. NMOS: Vg = 3V, Vd = 5V, source open. For different body connections, Vs is different

Tags: transistors, nmos

I simulated two circuits as shown below.

1. The body terminal is shorted to source terminal and the resulting source voltage is 5V.

[image]

2. The body terminal is shorted to ground and Vs = 1V (Vg - Vth). I can't understand the reason behind this.

[image]

Also in the second case, why should Vov be zero. Why can't Vs be equal to Vg?

Thanks

Comment: If the source is floating, the only current can come from the drain-source leakage and the body diode leakage.

Comment: Yes, the body current is almost zero. So is the drain current. Since the source is floating the current could be 1 femtoampere and the source would still be at 1V.

Comment: *Why can't Vs be equal to Vg?* **Why** should Vs and Vg be equal? what makes you think they should? I mean, they're not connected in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: What is the voltage at node x?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT98xl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A: depends on the channel leakage of the MOSFET and the leakage current of the diode.

Comment: Although this does explain what happens to the source voltage, this isn't exactly the same situation as OP is asking. If you put 3 V DC at the gate using a Vdc then it would be identical. Then at x you'd get Vs = 3 V - Vt due to the source-bulk diode's leakage current.